# How to circumvent the max_execution_time in PHP?

Tags: php, cron, mailing

I try to mailing messages to many subscribers. I need to execute my script **for a long time**, much more longer that is allowed with `max_execution_time`. I can use *Cron Tab*, which will be execute my script every time by schedule, but can I do it without cron tab? I try something like this:

```
    $maxTime = ini_get('max_execution_time');
    $startTime = time();
    foreach ($emails as $email) {
        if (time() < $startTime + $maxTime - 2) {
            // do something
        } else {
            // reload this page
        }
    }
```

And it's work well, but if I close this page in browser tab, it die and don't reload. I remind, that I'm looking for the implementation of this **without Cron Tab**. I want to start execution manually once and that to work it in the background later.

**NOTE:** Also I want to note that I **don't consider** the load on the server and send mail possible interval at this stage!

Comment: How about threaded php that will split the work within the limit not to trigger the execution timeout imposed by your hosting?

Comment: I can't disable max_execution_time at hosting. I have 30 seconds limit now

Comment: `set_time_limit(0);` to make it so that it will never timeout

Comment: @micb Thanks, but I'm using shared hosting, and `set_time_limit` function is disabled by hoster. (

Comment: "How can I cheat my hosting provider and get more than I pay for?" The right answer is - get a better hosting that lets you do what you want.

Comment: @DCoder I understand this ) But I was hoping that there is other solution

Comment: @Victor you could do it with a `header("Location: http://domain.com/process.php?lastId=1");`. After each record is sent the page would reload, then you just need to get it to pass the last ID you processed to the header function. Then you can get it to start where it left off. This should get around the 30sec timeout issue, but on shared hosting you may find that the company that hosts your site will get upset if you start using a lot of server resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

**Command Line**
Your best option is to run this on the command line manually. Command line scripts are much better for running long running processes.

**Shell Exec**
If you must run this via browser, you can trigger the command line script by using `exec` eg
`shell_exec('php -f /var/www/domain.com/myLongRunningProcess.php  > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &')`

**Ignore User Abort**
You can also run things after the browser has detached from a browser session. This is the most complex and hardest to debug but it will work. You must calculate the exact size of the page and then send the output and use the function `ignore_user_abort` so that your script will continue to run when the browser disengages.

Comment: I try to use `ignore_user_abort(TRUE)` but when my script automatically reload page, execution of the script stops (

Comment: Maybe just get a cheap vps

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking about it. But I don't understand why execution stops after page reload with `header()` function. (

Comment: OK, here's a tip. Use a javascript redirect instead of header. But yeah just get a vps

Comment: I think JS redirect doesn't work, because when the page is output something to browser - script execution already stopped.

Comment: not true, inline javascript gets executed immediately which is why everyone uses the document ready trick to avoid the standard behaviour of inline javascript